# Enabling checkbox in NATTable with data provider which is represented by a Boolean List

Tags: java, eclipse, nebula, nattable

We have a data model which is represented by a java bean which consists of a list of boolean rather than individual boolean instances.

```
public class MyModel {

  private String name;

  private String desc;

  private boolean check;

  private List<Boolean> flags ;

  //getters and setters go here
```

}

In the above code snippet, flags variable is used to represent the checkbox data in the UI 
I'am able to capture UI events triggered on **check** variable but not able to do so on **flags** variable

Unfortunately the list of boolean instance variable is not capturing the click events on the checkbox.

Is it possible to represent in such a manner?

Answer (score 0):

Well that depends on your implementation of the IDataProvider. The CheckboxCellEditor simply takes the current boolean value out of the data provider, switches to the opposite value and writes it back to the data provider.

Without knowing more about your data provider or data model, it is hard to help, but I assume your data provider does not update the data model correctly.

Comment: Hi user2955861, i have modified my question with additional info. Thanks

Comment: I'm still not sure what you are trying to achieve. But as you created the topic at the Eclipse Forum I will try to help you there. http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/603701/